# mysql using a DateTime in the whereclause

Tags: mysql

I tried this query below but it still returns days that had -1 values.  I want the where clause to return rows that are 2 days or newer.  Thanks!

```
SELECT uniqueKey,(TO_DAYS(TimeStampColumn) - TO_Days(Now())) as 'dayDiff'
 FROM couponextractor.tblresults
 where 'dayDiff' >= 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you just compare string 'daydiff' >= 0, which always evaluates to 0 => true

You need to get rid of quotes and use HAVING, beside that's very inefficient query... it's better to compute the date before and just use >= operator on the column.

HAVING dayDiff >= 0

So just compute the exact date, and then just do
WHERE TimeStampColumn >= "XXXX-XX-XX AA:AA:AA" so it can be optimized by the server if you have indexes.

Comment: ahh ty  SELECT uniqueKey,(TO_DAYS(TimeStampColumn) - TO_Days(Now())) as dayDiff
  FROM couponextractor.tblresults
  having dayDiff = 0

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the MYSQL DATEDIFF- Function?

```
 SELECT uniqueKey,DATEDIFF(TimeStampColumn,Now()) as 'dayDiff'
 FROM couponextractor.tblresults
 where DATEDIFF(TimeStampColumn,Now()) >= 1
```

Think this will do the job. Perhaps you have to cast the TimeStampColumn.